# WAMP - Reset Root password on mysql

Tags: mysql, wamp, password-recovery

I'm getting this error: `access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using paswword (NO).`

Its a fresh install of wampserver 2.2 32 bit.

Is there a way I can reset the mysql root password?

I have tried using mysqld.exe. --init-file=c:\reset.txt (below are the contents)

```
PDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Unfortunately this does not work, windows command prompt just hangs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the password 'pass' ?

Comment: yes but won't work. to clarify i typed: mysql -u root -p (and then typed pass)

Comment: mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('**Your new Password**') WHERE User='root';

Comment: yes tried that too, problem is that the cmd just hangs (i press ctrl+c to break after 30 sec)

Comment: just figured it out! windows doesn't like 'localhost' i need to type in 127.0.0.1 then it works

Comment: You might need to address "wampmysqld64" for newer versions, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that windows is not reading the HOSTS file properly, as a result only 127.0.0.1 is accepted NOT localhost.

To work around this:

Go to your wamp\apps\phpmyadmin.versionnumber\

Open config.inc.php

Change the localhost to 127.0.0.1

Save and restart all services